# How to CheckBoxList in DataTable show in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a DataTable with two columns like following:

```
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(CheckBoxList));

    DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
    dRow[0] = "A";

    CheckBoxList chk = new CheckBoxList();
    chk.Items.Add("x");
    chk.Items.Add("y");
    dRow[1] = chk;
    dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);

    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

In output GridView only show col1 and col2 **does not show**. how to show **CheckBoxList** in **col2** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `CheckBoxList` as type of a `DataColumn`(see below). It makes also no sense, the `GridView` does not take it into account anyway.

If you want to use a `CheckBoxList` in a `GridView` use a `TemplateField` and databound it in `RowDataBound` of the `GridView`.

The [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) property supports the following base .NET Framework data types:

```
Boolean
Byte
Char
DateTime
Decimal
Double
Guid
Int16
Int32
Int64
SByte
Single
String
TimeSpan
UInt16
UInt32
UInt64
Byte[]
```

Comment: i want add dynamically

Comment: @SamieyMehdi: You can add it dynamically, but you cannot use it in a datatable. Just add it to a TemplateField in a GridView column and fill it in `RowDataBound`. You can find it there via `e.Row.FindControl("CheckBoxListID")`